# Non-english url paths throwing 404 error in NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have found the same questions on StackOverflow and issues on GitHub but they couldn't help me. For example:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9804
[How to make non-english urls to work in next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390591/how-to-make-non-english-urls-to-work-in-next-js)

It is a Next.js app. I was requested to change the URL paths name from English to Russian,  after all, URLs show a 404 page.

If I navigate to:
`http://localhost:3000/новости`

Showing 404 error and throwing this in the console:
`GET http://localhost:3000/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8 404 (Not Found)`

As I searched, it seems an encoding related stuff but I didn't understand really, also as a solution they showed rewriting but I think it is extra work as I have some more pages and will be a lot

[image]

How I'm getting links is that I centralized the links data as an object using recoil so that I import anywhere (e.g: footer, header, etc) and map them to show links
[image]

I know there should be an easy solution but I'm not aware of cuz I'm not an expert, please help.

I really appreciate anybody trying to help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: By default next.js support English langauge

Comment: Does the `rewrites` solution provided in the question you linked not work for you?

Comment: @juliomalves didn't try it cuz it's extra work. I wanted a simple way to make it to understand non-english alphabetic urls but couldn't. So i changed back the path names to english

Answer (score -1):

By default next.js support English langauge
you can read this article to activate multi language support. [complete guide to activate multi language routing in Next.js](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-set-up-internationalization-in-react-using-lingui-js/)

You can read Nex.js default setting [Next international routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)